# Why does 302 redirect does not work in a iframe?

Tags: redirect, iframe, facebook-canvas

In facebook documentatin page [login for canvas](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-for-canvas/), they says:

> Because your application is being loaded in an iframe, returning a 302 to redirect the user to the Login Dialog will be unsuccessful.

What is the reason for a 302 redirect not working inside an iframe? Does it mean that if I have any redirect in my app, should I do it via javascript, as they suggest or only this one?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your app is in an iframe on the facebook website. So if they allowed that iframe to open  another facebook page, it would look like a "facebook inside of facebook".

When a user loads your app in a canvas page, Facebook sends you a `signed_request` via POST to that page. You can read about how to handle that in the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/signed-request/).

Comment: Everything you said makes sense, but does not answer my question.

Comment: I'm not sure if it accepts redirects to other sites or not. So your answer: try it and see what happens.

Comment: well, I did and apparently it works fine. This is why I would like to know why facebook developers wrote that.